# How can we send the request id that automatically gets generated by the RTK query as a header x-request-id?

Tags: rtk-query

I would like to access requestId that RTK generate for maintaining the cache for every request it fires and send it as a header under x-request-id.

Here's my slice

```
export const api = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000',
        prepareHeaders: (headers, { requestId }) => {
            headers.set('x-request-id', requestId)
        },
    }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getPage: builder.query<PageResponse, PageRequest>({
            query: (pageRequest) => {
                return {
                    url: '/api/4/page/fetch',
                    body: pageRequest,
                    method: 'POST',
                };
            },
        }),
    })
});
```

Is there a way we can access the `requestId` to be sent along in request headers?
See `type UseQueryResult<T>` [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, at this moment that is not being passed into the baseQuery (you can see relevant code [here](https://github.com/EskiMojo14/redux-toolkit/blob/9e593c12abc86adeb9999d6a75177221b34e51f0/packages/toolkit/src/query/core/buildThunks.ts#L332-L342)). But it's a neat idea. A pull request would be welcome.